# Unprotect excel sheet, insert a sheet row & re-protect a worksheet using Office scripts

Tags: excel, office-scripts

Using Office scripts I am looking to unprotect a sheet in excel (with a password), insert a sheet row at the location of the active cell, and the re-protect it with the "use autofilter" , "use pivot table and pivot chart" , "select unlocked cells"  and "select locked cells" options enabled - re-protecting with the same password.

I have managed to do this with VBA but want it to work in excel online - which I think Office scripts will do

but I have have no idea where to get started with Office scripts

Any help would be much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Please try.

```js
function main(workbook: ExcelScript.Workbook) {
    let ws = workbook.getActiveWorksheet();
    const shtPW: string = "ABC" // modify as needed
    if (ws.getProtection().getProtected()) {
        ws.getProtection().unprotect(shtPW);
        workbook.getActiveCell().getEntireRow().insert(ExcelScript.InsertShiftDirection.down);
        ws.getProtection().protect({}, shtPW);
    } else {
        workbook.getActiveCell().getEntireRow().insert(ExcelScript.InsertShiftDirection.down);
    }
}
```

- The sheet protection options should remain the same as before.

*Microsoft documentation:*

> [ExcelScript.WorksheetProtection interface](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/office-scripts/excelscript/excelscript.worksheetprotection?view=office-scripts&WT.mc_id=M365-MVP-33461)

> [getOptions()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/office-scripts/excelscript/excelscript.worksheetprotection?WT.mc_id=M365-MVP-33461&view=office-scripts#excelscript-excelscript-worksheetprotection-getoptions-member(1))

---

- If this is the first time you're protecting the worksheet, utilize the first argument to specify the options.

```js
   ws.getProtection().protect({ allowAutoFilter: true, allowDeleteColumns: false, allowDeleteRows: false,
            allowEditObjects: false, allowEditScenarios: false, allowFormatCells: false,
            allowFormatColumns: false, allowFormatRows: false, allowInsertColumns: false,
            allowInsertHyperlinks: false, allowInsertRows: false, allowPivotTables: true,
            allowSort: false, selectionMode: ExcelScript.ProtectionSelectionMode.normal }, shtPW);
```

Comment: Brilliant - many thanks - this works - I did have to include the second section even when the sheet was already protected